# Invalid Toolchain error uploading iOS 9.0 (for betatesting purpose) app to AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm developing a iOS app with `SDK 9.0` and `Xcode 7.0 beta (7A121l)`

When I try to upload my app to the AppStore, I can successfully validate my app but I can't successfully upload it to the store.

The error I get is the following

> Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the
>   public (GM) versions of Xcode6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. iOS 9
>   apps for internal TestFlight testers must be built with the latest
>   seed of the iOS SDK and uploaded with the latest seed of Xcode.

[image]

Comment: "Must be built with the public (GM) versions..." I.e- **not** beta

Comment: Yes! But, "iOS 9 apps for internal TestFlight testers must be built with the latest seed of the iOS SDK and uploaded with the latest seed of Xcode." Read my title: iOS 9.0. I will edit with for betatesting purpose

Comment: The latest Xcode is `Xcode 7 beta 6`

Comment: @Cy-4AH your comment is the right answer, thanks